# Magento - Get 2 column Product Landing page (Grid View)

Tags: css, magento

I would like to have a two column Product landing page in my grid view. So say two columns and may be restrict the rows to 4.

Is there a setting in the back end that I can change to achieve this? Or maybe change catalog.xml to achieve this effect?

Also can the pager and sorter be modified /styled to look like this 
[image: Pager / Sorter]

Any help is appreciated. Hopefully this is something very simple but just that I am unaware.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the pager toolbar can be styled like that through the use of `CSS`

**Limit the Rows (products)**

The **rows** (products) can be done in the Magento backend

Go to **System** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **Frontend (expand tab)**

Look for these:

```
Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values 
Products per Page on Grid Default Value
```

To limit to only 8 total products (2 rows & 4 columns) add your number (in this case 8) to both sets of values.

**Limit the Columns**

First I'd try this method: http://www.eliasinteractive.com/blog/magento-quick-change-in-column-count-for-products-displaying-in-category-listing-grid-view/

It is laid out nicely and easy to follow.

**If that doesn't work for some reason try this:**

Go to **app/design/frontend/[package]/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml**
*Copy **list.phtml** file to your `theme` if not there already*

Scroll about 1/2 way down and find this section

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
```

Now find this line:

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

and replace it with this:

```
<?php //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $_columnCount = 2; ?>
```

This should get your your desired results! Don't forget to edit the **column widths** in CSS